# ColdFusion CSV export - Unit numbers converting into dates

Tags: csv, coldfusion

I've inherited this code and it's pretty ugly. But, we're trying to address a problem whereby street unit numbers, e.g. the "3/14" or "3-14" are changing into dates in the CSV file, e.g. "1/04/2013" or "Apr-13".

I tried inserting a single quote to the front of the unit number before exporting. But this hasn't worked.

```
<cfset header2="Unit No.,Address line 1" & chr(13)>
<cfset records2="">
<cfloop query="q_reg">
     <cfset sUnitNumber = "">
     <!-- I've added the below to insert the single quote -->
     <cfif len(trim(unitnumber))>
          <cfset sUnitNumber = replace(unitnumber, ",", " ", "ALL")>
          <cfset sUnitNumber = insert(sUnitNumber,"'",1)>
     </cfif>
     <cfset records2= records2 & '#sUnitNumber#,#Replace(streetnumber, ",", " ", "ALL")#' & chr(13)>
</cfloop>
<!-- If I output "records2", I see my single quote -->          
<cfoutput>#records2#</cfoutput>
<cffile action="write" charset="utf-8" file="#pth##filename2#" output="#header2# #records2#" addnewline="no" attributes="normal">
```

As mentioned, this doesn't prevent the unit number changing to a date. I think I'm expecting a csv to behave like an excel, which probably isn't happening.

Any ideas how to prevent this problem?

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, problem was related to something else meaning the app was reading the wrong code. I've discovered that the unit number IS changing, BUT it now appears in the CSV with the apostrophe visible, i.e. `'4/13`

Ideally, it should appear without the apostrophe.

Comment: *RE:changing into dates in the CSV file* Do you mean those values are displayed as dates when the CSV is opened in Excel? Because unless there is something else going on in the code, the actual file should contain the extract strings you entered. Also, what version of Excel? I tried your code and it displays the correct values, albeit with a leading single quote:  `'3/14` and `'3-14`

Comment: Yep, my fault. I've added an edit to the OP. You're exactly right.